# Please install the postgres adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgres-adapter`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

When run server rail fail.

jhipster@jhipster-VM:~/Escritorio/witcamp$ gem li

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
actionmailer (2.2.2) 
actionpack (2.2.2)
activerecord (2.2.2)
activerecord-postgresql-adapter (0.0.1)
```

**database.yml**

```
development:
  adapter: postgres  
  encoding: unicode   
  database: witcamp   
  pool: 5  
  username: root   
  password: 123456

test:
  adapter: postgres
  encoding: unicode
  database: witcamp
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 123456
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your database.yml file should be.

**adapter: postgresql**

Also, in GemFile must have:  **gem 'pg'**